# Trouble with custom login page

Tags: customization, login

I am trying to make a partner portal page (page for our business partners to see important information specific to them) and therefore wanted to create a custom login page.

I have read many tutorials online, and I am following the directions exactly but it is just not working.

I am making the login page by making a page template and putting it into my custom theme.

Here is the template code:

```
<?php 
/** 
* Template Name: Log in
*/ 
get_header(); 


if($_POST) { 

global $wpdb; 

//We shall SQL escape all inputs 
$username = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['username']); 
$password = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['password']); 
$remember = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['rememberme']); 

if($remember) $remember = "true"; 
else $remember = "false"; 

$login_data = array(); 
$login_data['user_login'] = $username; 
$login_data['user_password'] = $password; 
$login_data['remember'] = $remember; 

$user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, false );

if ( is_wp_error($user_verify) ) { 
    echo '<span class="mine">Invalid Login Details</span>'; 
} else { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='". home_url() . '/partner-portal/' ."'</script>"; 
    exit(); 
} 
} else {  

}?> 

<form id="wp_login_form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/login/" 
method="post">
<div><img src="this-is-an-image.png"/></div>
<label for="tab-1" class="tab">Sign In</label><br>

<label class="my-username" >Username</label><br> 
<input type="text" name="username" class="text" value=""><br> 
<label class="my-password" >Password</label><br>

<input type="password" name="password" class="text" value=""> <br> 
<label> 
<input class="myremember" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever"> 
<span class="hey">Remember me</span></label> 
<br><br> 
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submit" value="Login"> 
</form>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Notes: When I enter incorrect credentials I get the "Invalid login details" as is expected.

When I enter correct credentials it redirects me to the /partner-portal/, however running a quick is_user_logged_in() shows me that the user is not logged in.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First of all... Why do you run wpdb->escape on request data at the beginning? It makes no sense at all (password CAN contain ' character for example)...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set below code in else condition

```
wp_clear_auth_cookie();     
wp_set_current_user($user_verify ->ID);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_verify ->ID, true);
```

hope this will help you and let me know if this is help or not

Comment: That did not work for me either.

It has the same issue as before.
It will redirect to the next page, but it still says i'm not logged in.

I found a temporary fix for now.
Instead of using this completely custom login page I am just using wp_login_form() and customizing the design with javascript.